# How to transform tensorflow PrefetchDataset to use it with ImageDataGenerator for data augmentation?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I am pretty new to tensorflow and keras and I have an ussue with working "cats_vs_dogs" tensorflow dataset. I am loading it using the `tfds.load()` function, which gives me an object of type `PrefetchDataset`. I need to add data augmentation to the training split of this dataset and I'd like to use the `tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator` with it's `flow()` function. I tried to transform my dataset as follows:

```
trainDataset = list(trainDataset)
trainDataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(trainDataset)
```

but I keep getting `InvalidArgumentError: cannot compute Pack as input #1(zero-based) was expected to be a uint8 tensor but is a int64 tensor [Op:Pack] name: 0`.

Without this transformation, when calling this function :

```
train_generator = train_datagen.flow(trainDataset, batch_size = 20)
```

I get `float() argument must be a string or a number, not 'PrefetchDataset'`.

How can I transform this dataset to be able to use it with ImageDataGenerator?
Or which other apporach can I use for data augmentation in this case?

Answer (score 0):

I know it's been a while but to solve this you could use the `.as_numpy_iterator` method that's built in the tf.data API.

For example if you want to print all rows:

```
for element in train_data.as_numpy_iterator():
   print(element)
```

You can see it in the doc here: https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/data/Dataset

Happy coding